# Subsetting a large zoo object using window() drops times

Tags: r, zoo

Preamble: I have a large multi-variate zoo object. It contains several years of 60 minute interval data. I like to keep my data in large chunks and subset from the large chunk as I need to perform work. Normally, I'm doing prety basic stuff like just making graphs, but I'd like to move towards a deeper understanding of my data.

So. I'm taking my large data.csv file [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/2547dqa1kfyfilk/data.csv?dl=0). And doing the following:

```
library(zoo)
library(lubridate)
df <- read.csv(file.choose(), na.strings = "")
df$FLOW <- as.numeric(df$FLOW) # read.csv turns this row into a factor due to NAs.
df$NST_DATI <- mdy_hm(df$NST_DATI, tz = "UTC")
df.zoo <- read.zoo(df)
```

Say I want to subset this big chunk to only data from 2012. If I subset the df data.table I get this (Note that the times start at 2012-01-01 00:30:00, as expected):

```
> head(df[format(df$NST_DATI, "%Y") == 2012, ])
                 NST_DATI WATER_TEMP   PH SPEC_CONDUCT    DO PER_SATUR TURBIDITY    TDS  STAGE FLOW
35065 2012-01-01 00:30:00       0.82 6.48         40.3 13.24      92.5       2.6 0.0258 83.315  587
35066 2012-01-01 01:30:00       0.83 6.48         40.2 13.17      92.1       3.2 0.0257 83.313  585
35067 2012-01-01 02:30:00       0.85 6.44         40.1 13.11      91.8       3.8 0.0256 83.313  585
35068 2012-01-01 03:30:00       0.84 6.48         40.2 13.14      91.9       2.9 0.0257 83.313  585
35069 2012-01-01 04:30:00       0.86 6.48         40.2 13.10      91.7       2.9 0.0257 83.313  585
35070 2012-01-01 05:30:00       0.87 6.48         40.2 13.08      91.5       2.9 0.0257 83.312  583
```

When I subset using the `window()` function, I get a different result (Note that the times start at 2012-01-01 03:30:00).

```
head(window(df.zoo, start = "2012-01-01", end = "2012-12-31"))
                    WATER_TEMP   PH SPEC_CONDUCT    DO PER_SATUR TURBIDITY    TDS  STAGE FLOW
2012-01-01 03:30:00       0.84 6.48         40.2 13.14      91.9       2.9 0.0257 83.313  585
2012-01-01 04:30:00       0.86 6.48         40.2 13.10      91.7       2.9 0.0257 83.313  585
2012-01-01 05:30:00       0.87 6.48         40.2 13.08      91.5       2.9 0.0257 83.312  583
2012-01-01 06:30:00       0.90 6.48         40.3 13.09      91.7       2.9 0.0258 83.312  583
2012-01-01 07:30:00       0.94 6.49         40.3 13.01      91.3       2.9 0.0258 83.313  585
2012-01-01 08:30:00       0.95 6.46         41.3 12.98      91.1       2.8 0.0264 83.316  588
```

It's really grinding my gears as I can reproduce it for other years, too. Thanks for any insight!

Comment: Please make this reproducible so anyone else can paste it into the session and observe it. Do this by showing the input using `dput(...)`

Comment: The csv is linked to Dropbox above. It's pretty big... I dput'ed the data out of curiosity and it's a 4.5 mb file and crushes the browser when pasted.

Comment: Posts to SO should contains *minimal* data.  Cut it down sufficiently to easily show it while still illustrating the basic problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, it turns out that in the function `window()`, the `start` and `end` variables will inherit your system's time zone if not specified. Since `df.zoo` was specified with `tz = "UTC"` my computer's timezone stepped in and forced a three hour offset offset (UTC minus my time zone).

To get the expected result, the solution is:

```
window(df.zoo, start = as.POSIXct("2012-01-01", tz = "UTC"), end = as.POSIXct("2012-12-31", tz = "UTC")) # specify tz!!!!
```

C'est la vie...

Comment: Note that zoo does not know anything about POSIXct or any other index class.  That gives it great generality but it can't deal with the idiosyncrasies of particular classes so one does need to be explicit.  If you use chron then there are no time zones to deal with and this type of problem cannot occur.